# why the view pager show the last image of an array each time i select any image of them?

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, android-viewpager

what i am doing that i display a grid view and each time i select an image it should be displayed an a full screen activity .. also i added swipe screen on a view pager functionality so i can switch left and right between images .. so my code works fine but the problem is that each time i select an image it always show the last one in the array of images .. it doesn't show the correct image .. why that is happening ?

here is code for the fragment that contains the grid view :

public class WoodenBlinds extends Fragment {

```
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.wod_1, R.drawable.wod_2,
                R.drawable.wod_3, R.drawable.wod_4,
                R.drawable.wod_5, R.drawable.wod_6,
                R.drawable.wod_7, R.drawable.wod_8,
                R.drawable.wod_9
        };
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_wooden_blinds, container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
          try{
            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
                gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), mThumbIds)); 
          } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
            E.printStackTrace();
        }


            /**
             * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
             * */
            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity2.class);
                    // passing array index
                     i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                     i.putExtra("array", mThumbIds);
                        Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                         startActivity(i);
                }   
            });


        return view;    
    }


    }
```

and here is the code for the full screen activity:

```
public class FullImageActivity2 extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image_activity2);
         //get intent data

            Intent i = getIntent();

            Object[] s = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");
            Integer[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(s, s.length, Integer[].class);

 //Selected image id


    // Loop through the ids to create a list of full screen image views
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, newArray);
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < imageAdapter.getCount(); i1++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i1]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
//        
        images.add(imageView);
    }

    // Finally create the adapter
    ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);

    // Set the ViewPager to point to the selected image from the previous activity
    // Selected image id
    int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
}
```

i guess the problem is with this line of code :

```
Object[] s = (Object[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");
 Integer[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(s, s.length, Integer[].class);
```

because each time it display the last index .. Not the correct one .. any advice's ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the data in the Intent with this line :

```
int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
```

You don't read the position, but the image resource id... because you fill the Intent with this :

```
i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
```

So, you can try to fill the Intent with

```
i.putExtra("id", position);
```